# Question regarding memory allocation in C

Tags: c, memory

I am having a difficult time getting why the answer is 66 bytes to the following question:

How much memory gets allocated for the data passed through the pointer in the main functions 2nd parameter(not considering the pointer size) in a 64 bit system, if the app is run with

```sh
./program alfa beta gamma
```

Comment: @pmg Yes. I'm new to stackowerflow, should I rewrite the question, so it say that?

Comment: "2nd parameter" .... do you mean `argv[1]` (pointer to array `"alfa"` somewhere in memory)? or `argv` itself ... when `argc` would be the 1st parameter?

Comment: argc is the first parameter and I'd like to know argv-s size in bytes.
argv[0] = ./app
argv[1] = alpha
argv[2] = beta
argv[3] = gamma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could come up with is

`argv[0]` ==> 8 bytes for pointer itself + 6 bytes for the data (`"./app"`) ==> **14**
`argv[1]` ==> 8 bytes for pointer itself + 5 bytes for the data (`"alfa"`) ==> **13**
`argv[2]` ==> 8 bytes for pointer itself + 5 bytes for the data (`"beta"`) ==> **13**
`argv[3]` ==> 8 bytes for pointer itself + 6 bytes for the data (`"gamma"`) ==> **14**
`argv[4]` ==> 8 bytes for the pointer (`NULL`) ==> **8**

TOTAL: 62

Maybe add 4 bytes for `argc` for **66** bytes??

Comment: It is my bad, I unintentionally translated the part after ./ . The original problem was with ./program , not ./app . This is the right answer.